# Where is Polymer paper-button.html?

Tags: polymer

I did the following:

```
bower init
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.1.0
```

But I don't see paper-button.html anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paper elements are not included in the Polymer package. You can either install them individually or all together. The following installs the paper button.

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-button
```

And this all paper elements

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-elements
```

Comment: I issued `bower install --save PolymerElements/gold-elements` and it installed the gold elements. Is there a way to get all the elements in the catalog?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to install them all in one go.